# How do I make contains case-insensitive in ef core 2?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, contains

I am trying to filter a list by a search string. It says [in the doc on the blue note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page) that:

- IQueryable gives you the database provider implementation of `Contains`.
- `IEnumerable` gives you the .NET Framework implementation of `Contains`
- The default setting of SQL Server instances is case-insensitive.
- Using `ToUpper` to make an explicit case-insensitive call should be avoided because it has a performance penalty.

My filtering is as follows:

```
IQueryable<ApplicationUser> customers = 
    from u in _context.Users
    where (u.Customer != null && u.IsActive)
    select u;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    customers = customers.Where(s => s.Email.Contains(searchString));
}
```

This solution however is case-sensitive, and I don't really understand why: since I'm using `IQueryable`, it should use the database provider implementation, that is case-insensitive by default, right?

I'm using EF Core 2 and currently just running a local MSSQLLocalDB.

Comment: You could eqialize them using String.ToLower() and then compare those temporary strings. You may also want to run String.Normalize() on it, just to avoid Unicode inconsistencies. Note that there can be significant processing, memory, and GC load with creating that many Strings in a loop. Strings are the wierdest class out there  See this article on comparing equality in general: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18714/Comparing-Values-for-Equality-in-NET-Identity-and

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)

Comment: Yes calling ToLower() or Normalize() would have the exact same performance overhead as ToUpper() as in my 4th bullet point. I am looking to avoid that and the best solution might just be to change my collation settings in my db

Comment: @JasonReddekopp Questions about `string` processing in .Net have little relevance to LINQ to SQL queries.

Comment: String.Contains is case-sensitive so that part is to be expected. If you skip that part doesn't the db give you back all the Users in the Context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

starting from version 2.1 of the EF Core, you can use HasConversion(). But the information in the database will be stored in lowercase:

```
builder.Property(it => it.Email).HasConversion(v => v.ToLowerInvariant(), v => v);
```

I solved a similar problem. This change solved all my problems.

Answer (score 4):

You would be better off using `LIKE` operator, e.g.

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    customers = customers.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Email, $"%{searchString}%"));
}
```

Comment: Because whoever reads your code now has clear intent? `.Contains()` would (you would hope) translate to `LIKE` anyway, but it may not be obvious to someone who has just read the code.

Re: case sensitivity -> that is definitely in the collation settings of your db?

Comment: @zaitsman The intent isn't to do a pattern match using `LIKE`. The intent is to check whether `Email` contains the specified value, and `s.Email.Contains(searchString)` documents that intent best. All you should care about is whether it's successfully translated to SQL. The best way to do it may or may not be using `LIKE`.

Comment: @zaitsman Whoever reads the code is likely a C# programmer, who knows exactly what `Contains` does, and may not be familiar with SQL and it's strange wildcards.

Comment: Contains in ef core does not convert to a like statement, it converts to a CHARINDEX() expression

Answer (score 1):

StringComparison is answer for me.

customers = customers.Where(s => s.Email.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

OR

customers = customers.Where(s => s.Email.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

works for me.