# Failing mapping of an scaffolded class from a postgres database

Tags: .net-core

To connect my dotnet 7 application to Postgres 14 I am using:

appsettings.json:

```
  {
    "ConnectionStrings": {
      "profiles_editor_data": "Server=myServer;Port=MyPort;Database=MyDB;User 
  Id=myUser;Password=MyPassword"
    },
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      },
   "AllowedHosts": "*"
  }
```

The Scaffolding from database created the next class:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string? Picture { get; set; }

    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;

    public string? Emails { get; set; }

    public string? PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

    public string? Overview { get; set; }

    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Position>? Positions { get; set; } = new List<Position>();

    public virtual ICollection<UserWebsite>? UserWebsites { get; set; } = new List<UserWebsite>();
}
```

From a table that I created using:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    picture       TEXT,
    first_name    VARCHAR(1000),
    last_name     VARCHAR(1000),
    username      VARCHAR(1000) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    emails        VARCHAR(2000),
    phone_numbers VARCHAR(2000),
    overview      TEXT,
    updated_on    TIMESTAMP
);
```

To work with this database I created a file called:  AppDbContext.cs containing:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using vivo_prof_editor.Models;

namespace vivo_prof_editor.Data
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public AppDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            // connect to postgres with connection string from appsettings.json

            Console.WriteLine("AppDbContext>OnConfiguring>");
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("profiles_editor_data"));
        
        }

        public DbSet<User> users {get; set;}

    }
}
```

From one of my controllers I am running:

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

    string mydbc = builder.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["profiles_editor_data"];


    AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext(builder);
    
    var nuser = new User() { FirstName="Joe", LastName="doe", Username="jodoe", Emails = "jodoe@mysite.com"};
    db.users.Add(nuser);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

I am getting the error:

```
PostgresException: 42703: column "Emails" of relation "users" does not exist
```

Am I missing something? It is true the table does not contain the Emails column but it has the emails column and the class was created by scalffolding  from the database using:

```
 dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ......
```

Is there a mapping I need to create to map the fields of my User class to the database users table columns?

Comment: Your table uses `emails` but EF uses `Emails` - while SQL DDL is usually case-insensitive, your Postgres instance might be using case-sensitive object names. What happens if you use exact column names with EFCore via the `[Column("emails")]` attribute (or `ConfigureEntity` method approach)?

Comment: In  Postgres table names are always lowercase. I need to confess I am just starting doing this mapping stuff. I will try both of your ideas. Thx

Comment: You were right. I started to use the annotation [Column(users)]  from System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Following a suggestion from a comment from @Dai I updated my User class to:

```
public partial class User
{
    [Column("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Column("picture")]
    public string? Picture { get; set; }

    [Column("first_name")]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("last_name")]
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; } = null!;

    [Column("emails")]
    public string? Emails { get; set; }

    [Column("phone_numbers")]
    public string? PhoneNumbers { get; set; }

    [Column("overview")]
    public string? Overview { get; set; }

    [Column("updated_on")]
    public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }

    [Column("positions")]
    public virtual ICollection<Position>? Positions { get; set; } = new List<Position>();

    [Column("user_websites")]
    public virtual ICollection<UserWebsite>? UserWebsites { get; set; } = new List<UserWebsite>();
}
```

and all started to work!!

Some one also suggested to use:

[Case insensitive name of tables and properties in Entity Framework 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914530/case-insensitive-name-of-tables-and-properties-in-entity-framework-7)

but I could not understand the answers here.