# 42703: column b.Id does not exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, npgsql

I have a naive EF implementation with Postgresql which is returning me the error

```
{"42703: column b.Id does not exist\r\n\r\nPOSITION: 8"}. Perhaps you meant to reference the column "b.id".
```

The code is as simple as

```
await _dbContext.BlackList.FindAsync(1);
```

The model is defined as

```
 [Table("blacklisted_people", Schema ="public")]
 public class BlackListedPeople
 {
     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }
    
 }
```

The db context is defined as

```
public class ApplicationDbContext:DbContext
 {
     public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> dbContextOptions)
         : base(dbContextOptions)
     {}

     public DbSet<BlackListedPeople> BlackList { get; set; }
 }
```

The table is defined in postgresql as

```
create table blacklisted_people
(
    id integer not null primary key
)
```

Comment: The datatype for the `Id` in your entity should be `long` type, as based on your table schema.

Comment: Thanks, I made the sql as integer but the error remained the same. I'll update in question also.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35914530/861716

Comment: Otherwise, you need to apply the `ColumnAttribute` to the `Id` property: `[Column("id")]` or you need to specify the exact column name in EF Fluent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, EF maps column names to the exact .NET property name, so it generates SQL expecting an `Id` column in the database, but your actual column name is `id`.

You can manually configure the property's column name ([EF docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#column-names)), or possibly try to use the [EFCore.NamingConventions](https://github.com/efcore/EFCore.NamingConventions) if the naming translation is systematic snake-case, for example.

Comment: yep, had to add column names, and it started working.